# Send mail using setTimeout

Tags: node.js, promise, settimeout, nodemailer

I'd like to send emails each 200ms, but it seems not working with promises :

**My function :**

```
SendMail.send = function(from, to, subject, body, name, logo) {
  var transporter, html,
      contactparam = _.find(options.blocks, { name: 'contactparam' }).params,
      smtpUsername = _.find(contactparam, { name: 'smtp_username' }),
      smtpPassword = _.find(contactparam, { name: 'smtp_password' }),
      smtpHost = _.find(contactparam, { name: 'smtp_host' }),
      smtpPort = _.find(contactparam, { name: 'smtp_port' }),
      compagny = _.find(contactparam, { name: 'compagny' }),
      firstname = _.find(contactparam, { name: 'firstname' }),
      facebookUrl = _.find(_.find(options.blocks, { name: 'socialparam' }).params, { name: 'facebook' }).value,
      twitterUrl = _.find(_.find(options.blocks, { name: 'socialparam' }).params, { name: 'twitter' }).value,
      linkedinUrl = _.find(_.find(options.blocks, { name: 'socialparam' }).params, { name: 'linkedin' }).value,
      secondaryColor = _.find(_.find(options.blocks, { name: 'themeparam' }).params, { name: 'secondary_color' }).value,
      loadedLogo = logo || _.find(_.find(options.blocks, { name: 'logoparam' }).params, { name: 'logo' }).value,
      websiteUrl = _.find(_.find(options.blocks, { name: 'mainparam' }).params, { name: 'url' }).value,
      templateFile = fs.readFileSync('./app/views/0-templates/' + options.template + '/mail.ejs', 'utf-8'),
      loadedName = name || (compagny && compagny.value) || (firstname && name && firstname.value + ' ' + name.value),
      ejsTemplate = ejs.compile(templateFile);

  html = ejsTemplate({
    logo: loadedLogo || '/images/LOGO.png',
    websiteUrl: websiteUrl,
    body: body,
    title: subject,
    facebookUrl: facebookUrl,
    twitterUrl: twitterUrl,
    linkedinUrl: linkedinUrl,
    secondaryColor: secondaryColor || '#1c1c1c'
  });

  if ((smtpUsername && smtpUsername.value !== '') && (smtpPassword && smtpPassword.value !== '') && (smtpHost && smtpHost.value !== '') && (smtpPort && smtpPort.value !== '')) {
    transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: smtpHost.value,
      pool: true,
      port: parseInt(smtpPort.value, 10),
      auth: {
        user: smtpUsername.value,
        pass: smtpPassword.value
      }
    });
  } else {
    transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      sendmail: true,
      newline: 'unix',
      path: '/usr/sbin/sendmail'
    });
  }

  return transporter.sendMail({
    from: loadedName + ' <' + from + '>',
    replyTo: from,
    to: to,
    subject: subject,
    html: html
  });
};

SendMail.arraySend = function(array) {
  var promises = [];
  promises = array.map(function (emailObj, index) {
    return new Promise(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        return sendMailHelper.send(emailObj.from, emailObj.to, emailObj.title, emailObj.htmlMessage);
      }, 200 * index);
    });
  });
  return promises;
};
```

**Using my function :**

```
Promise.all(sendMailHelper.arraySend(emailsArray)).then( function() {
  request.flash('success', 'Emails sent !');
  response.redirect('/');
});
```

**emailsArray :**

```
emailsArray.push({
  from: from,
  to: registration.cfc_user.email,
  title: 'Finale : ' + newTournament.name,
  htmlMessage: htmlMessage
});
```

**Issue :** emails are not sent.

Comment: You never resolve or reject that Promise.

Comment: Also, If you want 200ms between emails, it might be better to produce a single promise and chain it with `.then()`s to add each successive send.

Comment: So, can you help me using my code ?

Comment: Would be easier to accomplish using async/await but not sure if your setup supports that? Try reading this and see if it helps: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#promises-in-series

Comment: Is `SendMail.send()` the same as `sendMailHelper.send()` and has it been unit tested?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to actually *resolve* the promises you create. Without resolving (or rejecting) them, `Promise.all` will wait forever.

Also, [`.sendMail()`](https://nodemailer.com/usage/#sending-mail) returns a Promise when called, so this can be leveraged to make sure the delayed Promise is resolve only after the actual sending is completed:

```js
SendMail.arraySend = function(array) {
  var promises = array.map(function (emailObj, index) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { //<-- add the resolve/reject parameters
      setTimeout(function () {
        sendMailHelper
          .send(emailObj.from, emailObj.to, emailObj.title, emailObj.htmlMessage)
          .then(resolve)  // <-- resolve the Promise once execution is done
          .catch(reject); // <-- reject on failure
      }, 200 * index);
    });
  });
  return promises;
};
```

This will launch all Promises at once, but each will trigger within 200ms of each other. The actual sending might need some time but eventually everything will be done.

Alternatively, you can set it up so *after* each Promise is done, you wait 200ms and then launch another one. This will mean that you get a single Promise object in the end, not an array but it's guaranteed that messages are sent sequentially. It is easy to do this using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Running_Promises_in_Sequence)

```js
//helper function that converts email objects to be sent into Promises
const delayedSend = (emailObj, delay) => () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(
      () => sendMailHelper.send(emailObj.from, emailObj.to, emailObj.title, emailObj.htmlMessage)
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject);
      }, 
      delay
    )
  })
}

SendMail.arraySend = function(array) {
  var promises = array.reduce(function (sequence, emailObj) {
//                     ^^^^^^ reduce to convert to a single Promise
    return sequence.then(delayedSend(emailObj, 200)); // <-- chain .then() and delay each following execution
  }, Promise.resolve());
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ initial value is a simple resolved Promise.  
  return promises;
};
```

Comment: It does not work, no emails are sent using your code... Are you using Promise.all() to execute the function for each emails ?

Comment: @tonymx227, `Promise.all()` doesn't execute anything, rather is "aggregates" an array Promises, each of which represents the result of an asynchronous process that is already underway. The pattern in this answer doesn't require `Promise.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not `return` from a function called in a timeout. Also, it does not seem like a good idea to call that many Promises.

Best way is to group all your emails within a single Promise, returning an object of emails sent and emails with errors:

```
SendMail.arraySend = array => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let sent = [];
        let errors = [];

        const finalise = () => {
            if ((sent.length + errors.length) >= array.length) {
                resolve({ sent, errors });
            }
        };

        array.forEach((emailObj, index) => {
            setTimeout(function () {
                sendMailHelper.send(emailObj.from, emailObj.to, emailObj.title, emailObj.htmlMessage)
                .then(() => {
                    sent.push(emailObj);
                    finalise();
                });
                .catch(() => {
                    errors.push(emailObj);
                    finalise();
                })
            }, 200 * index);
        });
    });
};
```